# Combine Future block called multiple times when using Flatmap and multiple subscribers

Tags: ios, combine

I've been successfully using [BrightFutures](https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures) in my apps mainly for async network requests. I decided it was time to see if I could migrate to [Combine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine). However what I find is that when I combine two [Futures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/future) using [flatMap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/future/3333364-flatmap) with two subscribers my second [Future](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/future) code block is executed twice. Here's some example code which will run directly in a playground:

```swift
import Combine
import Foundation

extension Publisher {
    func showActivityIndicatorWhileWaiting(message: String) -> AnyCancellable {
        let cancellable = sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in Swift.print("Hide activity indicator") }, receiveValue: { (_) in })
        Swift.print("Busy: \(message)")
        return cancellable
    }
}

enum ServerErrors: Error {
    case authenticationFailed
    case noConnection
    case timeout
}

func authenticate(username: String, password: String) -> Future<Bool, ServerErrors> {
    Future { promise in
        print("Calling server to authenticate")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            promise(.success(true))
        }
    }
}

func downloadUserInfo(username: String) -> Future<String, ServerErrors> {
    Future { promise in
        print("Downloading user info")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            promise(.success("decoded user data"))
        }
    }
}

func authenticateAndDownloadUserInfo(username: String, password: String) -> some Publisher {
    return authenticate(username: username, password: password).flatMap { (isAuthenticated) -> Future<String, ServerErrors> in
        guard isAuthenticated else {
            return Future {$0(.failure(.authenticationFailed)) }
        }
        return downloadUserInfo(username: username)
    }
}

let future = authenticateAndDownloadUserInfo(username: "stack", password: "overflow")
let cancellable2 = future.showActivityIndicatorWhileWaiting(message: "Please wait downloading")
let cancellable1 = future.sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
    switch completion {
    case .finished:
        print("Completed without errors.")
    case .failure(let error):
        print("received error: '\(error)'")
    }
}) { (output) in
    print("received userInfo: '\(output)'")
}
```

The code simulates making two network calls and `flatmap`s them together as a unit which either succeeds or fails.
The resulting output is:

> `Calling server to authenticate`
>   `Busy: Please wait downloading`
>   `Downloading user info`
>   `Downloading user info`     <---- unexpected second network call 
>   `Hide activity indicator`
>   `received userInfo: 'decoded user data'`
>   `Completed without errors.`

The problem is `downloadUserInfo((username:)` appears to be called twice. If I only have one subscriber then `downloadUserInfo((username:)` is only called once. I have an ugly solution that wraps the `flatMap` in another `Future` but feel I missing something simple. Any thoughts?

Comment: When you create the actual publisher with `let future`, what if you add `.share`, so that your two subscribers subscribe to a single pipeline?

Comment: By the way I would not use two subscribers at all. I’d stick a `handleEvents` operator in the pipeline before the sink. You don’t need the overhead of a second subscriber just to drive a spinner.

Comment: @matt adding `.share` solves the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing: you need to wrap a Deferred around each of your futures. Otherwise they fire prematurely.

Comment: Okay, I’ll give that as an answer. But I would prefer to critique the whole pipeline! :)

Comment: @matt feel free to critique the whole pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the actual publisher with `let future`, append the `.share` operator, so that your two subscribers subscribe to a single split pipeline.

**EDIT:** As I've said in my comments, I'd make some other changes in your pipeline. Here's a suggested rewrite. Some of these changes are stylistic / cosmetic, as an illustration of how I write Combine code; you can take it or leave it. But other things are pretty much *de rigueur*. You need Deferred wrappers around your Futures to prevent premature networking (i.e. before the subscription happens). You need to `store` your pipeline or it will go out of existence before networking can start. I've also substituted a `.handleEvents` for your second subscriber, though if you use the above solution with `.share` you can still use a second subscriber if you really want to. This is a complete example; you can just copy and paste it right into a project.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    enum ServerError: Error {
        case authenticationFailed
        case noConnection
        case timeout
    }
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    func authenticate(username: String, password: String) -> AnyPublisher<Bool, ServerError> {
        Deferred {
            Future { promise in
                print("Calling server to authenticate")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    promise(.success(true))
                }
            }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    func downloadUserInfo(username: String) -> AnyPublisher<String, ServerError> {
        Deferred {
            Future { promise in
                print("Downloading user info")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    promise(.success("decoded user data"))
                }
            }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    func authenticateAndDownloadUserInfo(username: String, password: String) -> AnyPublisher<String, ServerError> {
        let authenticate = self.authenticate(username: username, password: password)
        let pipeline = authenticate.flatMap { isAuthenticated -> AnyPublisher<String, ServerError> in
            if isAuthenticated {
                return self.downloadUserInfo(username: username)
            } else {
                return Fail<String, ServerError>(error: .authenticationFailed).eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
        }
        return pipeline.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        authenticateAndDownloadUserInfo(username: "stack", password: "overflow")
            .handleEvents(
                receiveSubscription: { _ in print("start the spinner!") },
                receiveCompletion: { _ in print("stop the spinner!") }
        ).sink(receiveCompletion: {
            switch $0 {
            case .finished:
                print("Completed without errors.")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("received error: '\(error)'")
            }
        }) {
            print("received userInfo: '\($0)'")
        }.store(in: &self.storage)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
start the spinner!
Calling server to authenticate
Downloading user info
received userInfo: 'decoded user data'
stop the spinner!
Completed without errors.
```

Comment: thanks for the `.share` solution. I'm still a little confused why `share` is required after`FlatMap` and not when I call one of the `Future`s directly irrespective of how many subscribers might be attached. Is it because the `Future`s are transformed into a `Publisher` after `FlatMap`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Actually the mystery is why you _don't_ get "Calling server to authenticate" twice as well. I would expect the entire pipeline to be duplicated by the double subscription. This publisher is a struct; it has value semantics, and subscribing to it twice generates a double pipeline — that is, two separate pipelines. `share` wraps the publisher in a class so that you get reference semantics, so that the flow can be "split" to two subscribers. See my http://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsSplitters/operatorsshare.html for more about that.

Comment: OK, did a suggested rewrite. It's just a serving suggestion, but as you are in the process of migrating from another framework you might find it instructive.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very helpful. 
My understanding is that  `Future` has reference semantics; A "plain" `Future`'s operation is executed once, regardless of the number of subscribers. So to me it still seems somewhat surprising that when two `Future`'s are flatmapped  together the resultant pipeline behaves as though it has value semantics (at least for the second `Future`).

Comment: Yes, future is a class, but `.flatMap` is not, and AnyPublisher is not, so it all gets a bit confusing really. :) In your original code you flatten this type out with `some Publisher`, so heaven knows what it is; that is one reason I avoid this use of `some`. As you can see, I type everything to, and flatten everything to, AnyPublisher so I have a good idea what the types are at every junction.